# Calling a script with a setuid set

Tags: c, bash

I wanted to launch a bash script (read: bash not sh script) as a root not as the user calling it, however bash ignore `setuid` on scripts, so I chose to write a very small script that takes a script/arguments and call it with `setuid` set.

This worked well and I went even further to verify that the script has `setuid` set on, executable and `setuid()` called on the owner of the file and not as root, to avoid any misuse of the program and I ended up with the program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *command;
  int i, file_owner, size = 0;
  struct stat status_buf;
  ushort file_mode;

  // Check argc
  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s <script> [arguments]\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  // Make sure the script does exist
  if(fopen(argv[1], "r") == NULL) {
    printf("The file %s does not exist.\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
  }

  // Get the attributes of the file
  stat(argv[1], &status_buf);

  // Get the permissions of the file
  file_mode = status_buf.st_mode;

  // Make sure it's executable and it's setuid
  if(file_mode >> 6 != 567) {
    printf("The file %s should be executable and should have setuid set, please chmod it 0106755.\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
  }

  // Get the owner of the script
  file_owner = status_buf.st_uid;

  // setuid
  setuid(file_owner);

  // Generate the command
  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    size += strlen(argv[i]);
  }
  command = (char *) malloc( (size + argc + 11) * sizeof(char) );
  sprintf(command, "/bin/bash %s", argv[1]);
  if (argc > 2) {
    for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
      sprintf(command, "%s %s", command, argv[i]);
    }
  }

  // Execute the command
  system(command);

  // free memory
  free(command);

  return 0;
}
```

The exercise was not only to solve my problem, but it was also a way to get more into C, so what do you suggest? Is there anything I should improve?

Comment: Next time don't double post, just use the flag tool on your [original post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290670/need-help-improving-a-small-c-program) and ask a moderator to migrate it to the suggested site.

Comment: I'll make sure to do that next time, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check for errors in `stat`, `setuid`, `fork`, and `execvp`, to name a few.  If the exec fails in the child you should call `exit`.
2. Do you really want the **`p`** in `execvp`?  This is not guaranteed to be the same as the `argv[1]` you just `stat`-ed.  If `argv[1]` is `ls` your `stat` will look for a file at `./ls` and it will likely find the program in `/bin`.  I would use `execve` and either do that `PATH` lookup yourself or simply omit that part and require the user to specify a full path for something in `PATH` (eg. `/bin/ls` instead of just `ls`).
3. The `stat` + observe state + `exec` thing is a race condition.  Another process can change the attributes on the file in that timing window.  This may or may not be important to you.  Given that this is a security-ish program I would say it may very well be.
4. Instead of returning 0, you might want to return the child process's exit code (which you can get with `waitpid`.)  You might also want to return nonzero when the functions I mention in #1 fail.  This way a shell script or something calling you programmatically can determine success or failure.

Comment: That was very very helpful, thank you.. I would like to know more about #3, how could I prevent anyone from changing the file's attributes before calling exec, to avoid someone tempering with the attributes while the script is running? should I lock the file ?

Comment: I don't know if there is a good way around it for this.  I don't think `flock` makes sense here either.

Comment: I added V3 in my original post, I modified it following #1. #2 and #4, I still have to figure out how to fix #3

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you would install your program (edit V3) like this

```
$ gcc -o edit_v3 edit_v3.c
$ ls -l edit_v3
-rwxrwxr-x 1 erik erik 7698 2012-04-15 12:22 edit_v3
$ sudo chown root.root edit_v3
$ sudo chmod 4755 edit_v3
$ ls -l edit_v3
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 7698 2012-04-15 12:22 edit_v3
```

But a user could then easily get root access

```
$ ls -l /bin/su
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 31116 2011-06-24 11:37 /bin/su
$ ./edit_v3 /bin/su
# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) grupper=0(root),116(pulse),117(pulse-access)
```

It is difficult to write secure setuid programs. Over the years a lot of security vulnerabilities have been found in such program.

Instead of writing your own setuid program, you could also use **sudo**. You would then have to edit the configuration file **/etc/sudoers**

Comment: Actually it is one of the reasons why I abandoned the idea entirely, I wanted some way to provision server configuration (i.e Nginx conf files) but I finally settled on a more Capistrano/Chef solution as it's easier and well a lot safer than having any kind of security holes on the server. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I'd do is

change

```
sprintf(command, "%s %s", command, argv[i]);
```

to use strcat

while this does work on a number of implementations, it's not considered "safe"

refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283354/is-sprintfbuffer-s-buffer-safe

Comment: How about using `strncat()`?

Comment: thank you, I've already changed the script to use fork()/exec() instead of looping on the command variable myself, modified script is just above.